# Как реализовать многоуровненвый вывод коментариев

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Пытаюсь реализовать многоуровневый вывод комментариев. То есть, есть комментарий, у него могут быть ответы, у ответов так же могут быть ответы, и так далее.
Вот то  что я пробовал на данный момент
model

```
const Comments = sequelize.define('Comment', {
  text: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
})

// Устанавливаем самоссылочное отношение "hasMany" для модели Comment
Comments.hasMany(Comments, { as: 'Replies', foreignKey: 'parentId' })
```

service

```
async getListComments() {
    try {
      const list = await Comments.findAll({
        include: [
          {
            model: Comments,
            as: 'Replies',
            include: {
              model: Comments,
              as: 'Replies',
              hierarchy: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      })
      return list
    } catch (e) {
      throw createHttpError(500, e)
    }
  }
```

но таким образом я могу дойти только до второго уровня вложенности, а хотелось бы это как-то автоматизировать.

Comment: в sql есть такая штука, `WITH RECURSIVE`, она хорошо подходит для извлечения дерева комментариев. пример https://stackoverflow.com/a/71450099/4496422. ещё в `include` есть параметр `nested`, но я не уверен, что он подойдёт

Comment: @nörbörnën
я понимаю что в sql это есть, но хотелось бы всё же через ORM